# Perché quando si cambia una frase impersonale (con "si") cambia l'accordo del verbo?

Tags: agreement

Con la frase

> Si mangiano gli spaghetti

so che è scritto '*mangiano*' perché la parola *spaghetti* è plurale. Ma, se si vuole usare un pronome per gli spaghetti (*li* in questo caso), *mangiano* diventa *mangia*:

> Si mangiano gli spaghetti => Li si mangia. (Non, li si mangiano.)

Sono convinto (forse sbaglio) che questo è giusto ma è molto difficile trovare una spiegazione nei libri o siti (Treccani, Serianni, ecc.) che spiega perché.

Ritengo che sia "Li si mangia" e non "Li si mangiano" perché "li" è un pronome complemento e quindi non può diventare soggetto di una frase passiva (si passivante).

C'è un sito o libro che potrebbe confermare questo? O c'è un'altra spiegazione?

Comment: Non abbraccerei in toto la tua ipotesi sulla concordanza: "Ci sono diversi esempi. Li si trovano in x,y, z" per me è accettabilissimo.

Comment: @Marco: Mi sono presa la libertà di cambiare leggermente il titolo della domanda. Si ritieni però che sia migliore quello precedente, ovviamente puoi fare un "rollback".

Comment: Grazie @Charo, il tuo suggerimento è più chiaro.

Answer (score 2):

La spiegazione è nel fatto che, per quanto apparentemente simili, si tratta in realtà di due costruzioni diverse, come intuisci.

“Si mangiano gli spaghetti” è appunto un esempio del cosiddetto **si passivante**: è di fatto una [costruzione passiva](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/costruzione-passiva_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/), ma non costruita con un ausiliare (come in “sono/vengono mangiati gli spaghetti”). Quindi, analogamente alle altre forme del passivo, il soggetto grammaticale è “gli spaghetti”, nonostante a compiere l'azione sia qualcun altro, non menzionato.
Questo caso rientra nella situazione più generale delle *costruzioni anticausative*. Semplificando, il senso è semplicemente che, mentre in quelle causative si specifica chi esercita l'azione (“l'autista ferma l'autobus”), in quelle anticausative o decausative no (“l'autobus si ferma”). Se vuoi approfondire, trovi qualcosa in questa [tesi di dottorato](https://iris.univr.it/retrieve/handle/11562/916792/7915/TESI%20DOTTORATO%20FRATTER.pdf).

Per inciso, l'uso attuale prevede che nel caso del si passivante

> l’accordo è coerentemente dipendente dal soggetto: *si sentono urli*. Tuttavia, in toscano popolare, come in italiano antico, l’accordo al singolare (quindi di tipo impersonale) è diffuso, anche se è da considerarsi oggi substandard o molto letterario: *si sente urli* ([“accordo”, *Enciclopedia dell'italiano*](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accordo_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/)).

“Li si mangia”, detto sempre degli spaghetti, è invece una vera e propria [**costruzione impersonale**](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-impersonali_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/), in cui il soggetto non è espresso, ma il “si” si riferisce ugualmente a chi compie l'azione. Come spiega la pagina dell'*Enciclopedia dell'italiano* dell'ultimo link,

> Il si impersonale indica un partecipante umano, indefinito, dal riferimento generico (indeterminato o esistenziale [...]).
>
> Nell’interpretazione generica il *si* denota un gruppo di persone a cui si applica una proprietà, intesa come caratteristica del gruppo. [...]
>
> in questa casa si legge molto [si = «le persone che vivono in questa casa»]

ma sono possibili anche riferimenti specifici (“ieri si è bevuto molto a casa di Mario”).

Comment: @DaG La tua analisi non evidenzia l'uso dell'accordo di cui si parla nel post. Che si tratti di "si passivante" o di "si impersonale" il verbo è comunque al plurale in presenza di un complemento oggetto plurale.

Comment: @Charo Vedi mia specificazione.

Comment: Da un mio libro: "la costruzione ***si* impersonale** [...] si forma con **si** + 3ª persona singolare del verbo in tutti i tempi verbali". Un esempio da questo libro: "In questo ristorante **si mangiava** benissimo prima, [...]". "La costruzione ***si* passivante** si usa quando nella frase c'è anche il complemento oggetto del verbo principale e si forma con **si** + 3ª persona del verbo, al singolare o al plurale, a seconda del complemento oggetto che segue". Esempi da questo libro: "**Si parla** italiano. // **Si parlano** diverse lingue". Comp. ogg. tra virgolette: in realtà è il soggetto.

Comment: E se ne parla anche qui:  https://www.achyra.org/cruscate/viewtopic.php?t=2229.   Si cita dalla GGIC (in questo caso, si parla di "le mele"): "Se il compl. oggetto è un pronome clitico, per tutti gli italofoni sono accettabili le due varianti: quella con il compl. oggetto (583) e quella in cui il compl. oggetto diventa soggetto (584): // (583) Le si mangia. // (584) Esse/Ø si mangiano. // [...] In alcune varietà è accettata anche la forma *Le si mangiano*". Quindi, "le si mangiano" non è del tutto standard, ma è ammesso in alcune varietà.

Comment: @Charo Certo, certo: "In questo forum si leggono un mucchio di castronerie. Le si legge dappertutto"?? Dubito che la maggior parte degli utenti trovi l'uso verbale più comune di "le si leggono". Non hai notato che in  achyra.org/cruscate/viewtopic.php?t=2229 ci sono opinioni discordanti?

Comment: Per me l'importante di quel forum è la citazione dalla GGIC.

Comment: Gli anticausativi c'entrano ben poco qui. Questa categoria di verbi riflessivi si riferisce a cambiamenti di stato che possono essere effettuati sia da agenti sia da cause esterne/interne. "La porta si chiuse" = qualcuno chiuse la porta o la porta si chiuse per via del vento/da sé. Gli spaghetti non si autofagocitano. Il "si" in si mangiano gli spaghetti" è invece un vero e proprio "si impersonale": la gente mangia gli spaghetti.

Comment: @Nico: Scrivi alla redazione della Treccani per spiegare loro che sbagliano sul si passivante e sugli anticausativi: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accordo_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/

Comment: @DaG Lo farò sicuramente e ti ringrazio dell'accenno. Tra l'altro, il link che postano nel sito che citi non spiega per nulla cosa sono le costruzioni anticausative. In linguistica i verbi anticausativi sono quelli che esprimono un cambiamento di stato dovuto a cause esterne (agenti) o interne. "Rompersi" è un tipico esempio. "Il vaso si è rotto" può voler dire che  l'ha rotto qualcuno o che si è sgretolato per usura o altri fattori. Gli anticausativi si riferiscono al risultato finale e non alle cause. Se ti interessa il tema, fammi sapere.

Comment: Questo [articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/usi-e-funzioni-del-pronome-clitico-si/173) fa questo esempio di *si* passivante: "*si mangiano le mele*". E spiega: "Questa variante, che prende il nome di si 'passivante', è obbligatoria in molte varietà dell'italiano quando il complemento oggetto non è costituito da un pronome clitico". Riguardo al *si* impersonale spiega: "quando il complemento oggetto di un verbo transitivo è costituito da un pronome clitico, ad esempio *lo*, il clitico precede il si impersonale: *lo si seguirà con attenzione*".

Comment: @Charo I complementi oggetto sono una funzione sintattica che non ha nulla a che fare con la categoria di persona.

Comment: @Charo Questo articolo afferma anche che "La costruzione con il si passivante è possibile solo se il complemento oggetto è di terza persona, poiché con un complemento oggetto di prima o di seconda persona è invece d'obbligo l'impiego del si impersonale". I complementi oggetto sono complementi oggetto e non hanno nulla a che fare con la categoria di persona, che si riferisce a verbi o a pronomi. A volte bisogna anche filtrare attentamente le "Bibbie".

Comment: Nella domanda non appaiono complementi oggetto di prima o seconda persona, però.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! I was also confused about this kind of constructions and I found it really useful.